# grep broke after code change from inline to change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, grep

I think I have a change of scope issue.

I had a select box that fired an inline code for the on-change event.

I removed that inline code and created a onchange function instead. After I did that, grep seemed to break. It is not finding the properties of objects now.

old code - stripped down

```
function assignHiddenValue(o,s,h,n) {
...
d = oCombListData;
var eID = jQuery(this).val();
var edata = jQuery.grep(d, function (e) { 
                return e.idpower_effects_list === eID 
                });
            console.log('edata = ');
            console.log(edata);
            var ecost = edata[0].effect_cost;
}
```

Worked fine.

New code

```
jQuery("select[name='slctEffect']").change(function ($) {
...
d = oCombListData;
var eID = jQuery(this).val();
var edata = jQuery.grep(d, function (e) { 
                return e.idpower_effects_list === eID 
                });
            console.log('edata = ');
            console.log(edata);
            var ecost = edata[0].effect_cost;
});
```

Now I get this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'effect_cost' of undefined
```

What gives? The d (object array) and eID (int) show the data in console. But now grep is saying it can't find the property of the object.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What is purpose of `$` as parameter at `.change(function ($) {})` ?  What is `oCombListData` ? Can you create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Answer (score 0):

In your "inline" code I assume you're doing something like this:

```
<select name="slctEffect" onchange="assignHiddenValue(...)">
    ...
</select>
```

When this line `var eID = jQuery(this).val();` in your assignHiddenValue function is called, "this" will be the window.

In the "onchange" function from your new code, when `var eID = jQuery(this).val();` is called, "this" will be the select